# Javascript supplant

Tags: javascript, regex, web

I recently came across the `Javascript supplant` function by crockford. The function goes like this -

```
if (!String.prototype.supplant) {
    String.prototype.supplant = function (o) {
        return this.replace(/{([^{}]*)}/g,
            function (a, b) {
                var r = o[b];
                return typeof r === 'string' || typeof r === 'number' ? r : a;
            }
        );
    };
}
```

I need to understand the mechanics of this function and how exactly is this thing working. I have come across many explanations but all tend to make things complex by introducing technicalities that make things worse.

Trying to look for

1.The `regex` explanation here

2.the logic for the function(a,b) code block

3.the use of that return statement

Comment: Are you wanting someone to step through it, piece by piece?

Comment: Not exactly but just a simple translation of the logic... :)

Comment: @borax12 I'm fairly sure you've supplied a wrong code sample. I can tell by the spaces in the regex and the "smart" quotes in the code. Please post correct code or you will get wrong explanations. Also, did the text where you got that function from not contain an explanation?

Comment: Are you familiar with how to use it?

Comment: You can find Crockford's original code here at the bottom: http://javascript.crockford.com/remedial.html

Comment: This might help with the regex: [Regular expression explained with words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772594/regular-expression-explained-with-words)

Comment: @Tomalak- no ,i was watching the YUI library javascript video lecture and this was shown there.And crockfords own js page doesnt offer much help either 

just a simple explanation of what the arguments in the function block mean - ie a and b ?

Comment: @JaredFarrish-thanks for revising the code and yes i did refer to the page ,but doesnt offer much

Comment: This part of the MDN docs help explain what `String.replace()` is doing with the second argument: [Specifying a function as a parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#section_6)

Comment: @borax12 That is explained in the documentation to `String.replace()`. It's not complicated, either. Did you try to set a breakpoint in the debugger and step through the code line by line? This should explain very nicely what it does, and how it does it. The debugger is generally the first thing you should try when analyzing code. You can even find out what `a` and `b` do - without consulting the documentation.

Comment: @JaredFarrish-thanks a ton ,for the mdn page...made my day

Comment: @Tomalak-didnt test the code though...but the problem is solved

Comment: Take a look at the `console.log()` output on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/E53Tv/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as Tomalak said, spaces in regex are not trivial

1. the regex basically matchs something like this: `{ ... }`. the `[^{}]` means the content in the curly braces can be anything but curly nraces. The  `*` means the length of the content can be zero or any number. The part inside the parentheses is [Parenthesized Substring Matches](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Parenthesized_Substring_Matches)
2. The function passes a dictionary in as `o`, and performs a `replace` using the regex above. Whenever there is a match, the callback function of the `replace` will be invoked. `a` is the whole matched part, and `b` is the submatch part corresponding to the "Parenthesized Substring Matches". The callback function looks for `b` as the key in the dictionary, and return the corresponding value
3. the return statement means if the type of `r` is string or number, then return `r`; otherwise return `a`

You can checkout the [example code](http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/E53Tv/) provided by Jared Farrish, which shows how the match and replace work very clearly.

Comment: Here's a fiddle showing what the different variables are, which makes it easier to understand: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/E53Tv/ No offense, but I don't think this is a very thorough or plain explanation of what's going on inside.

Comment: @JaredFarrish i was in a hurry so i just tried to answer the questions one by one.. just updated the post, hope it's better now. btw, nice example!

Comment: @borax12 sure, hope it helps you understand the function :)